# Determine the optimal critical region for a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

$X_1,\dots, X_n$ is a simple random sample of $X\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. What is the optimal critical region $\alpha$ for $H_0:\lambda =\lambda_0$ against $H_1:\lambda=\lambda_1$?

I would use the Neyman-Pearson theorem to solve it. $$ \frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1} = \frac{(\lambda_0^{\sum x_i} e^{-\lambda_0}) / (\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!)}{(\lambda_1^{\sum x_i}e^{-\lambda_1})/(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!)} = \frac{\lambda_0^{\sum x_i}e^{\lambda_1}}{\lambda_1^{\sum x_i}e^{\lambda_0}}\leq k$$

Taking logarithms

$$ \ln \left( \lambda_0^{\sum x_i}e^{\lambda_1} \right)-\ln \left( \lambda_1^{\sum x_i}e^{\lambda_0} \right)\leq \ln(k)\\
\ln \left( \lambda_0^{\sum x_i}\right)+\ln\left(e^{\lambda_1} \right)-\ln \left( \lambda_1^{\sum x_i}\right)-\left(e^{\lambda_0} \right)\leq \ln(k)\\
\left(\sum x_i\right)\ln  (\lambda_0)+\lambda_1 -\left( \sum x_i \right)\ln \left( \lambda_1\right)-\lambda_0\leq \ln(k)\\
\left(\sum x_i\right)\left(\ln  (\lambda_0) -\ln \left( \lambda_1\right)\right)\leq \ln(k)+(\lambda_0-\lambda_1)\\
\sum x_i\leq \frac{\ln(k)+(\lambda_0-\lambda_1)}{\ln  (\lambda_0) -\ln \left( \lambda_1\right)}
$$

Now what would be the optimal critical region? This will depend of $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$ according to some criterion I cannot determine from the last equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made use of an unstated assumption that $\lambda_0>\lambda_1.$

You concluded that the rejection criterion is that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i < c$ where $c$ is the critical value.

If the level of the test is $\alpha$ then the critical value $c$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
& \Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le c \,\middle|\, \lambda = \lambda_0 \right) \le \alpha \\
\text{and} & \text{ (since only integer values are involved) } \\
& \Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge c+1 \,\middle|\, \lambda=\lambda_0 \right) >\alpha.
\end{align}
Given $\lambda_0$ and $\alpha,$ and recalling that $X_1+\cdots+X_n\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(n\lambda_0)$, use those two inequalities to find $c.$

Comment: Hello. The assumption you mentioned was not part of the problem. Could you point out where I used it? Maybe at the end when I divided?

Comment: @Cure : You used it when you divided both sides of an inequality by a difference of logarithms. If the quantity by which you divided were negative, you would have had to invert the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge c+1 \,\middle|\, \lambda=\lambda_0 \right) = 1 -  \Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c+1 \,\middle|\, \lambda=\lambda_0 \right) \frac{\Pr\left(\left(  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c+1 \right)\cap (\lambda=\lambda_0)\right)}{\Pr (\lambda=\lambda_0)}$?
The denominator is given by $\lambda\sim P(\lambda_0)$, but I'm not sure how to compute the numerator en relation to the $\cap (\lambda=\lambda_0)$ part.

Comment: @Cure : That kind of statement makes sense only when you have a probability distribution on $\lambda,$ and in that case, instead of a likelihood-ratio test, you'd probably be seeking the posterior probability distribution of $\lambda,$ i.e. its conditional distribution given $X_1+\cdots+X_n.$ And the thing that is complementary to $\cdots\ge c+1$ is $\cdots<c+1,$ not $\cdots\le c+1. \qquad$

Comment: Is there a closed form for $c$? I haven't been able to find one since. I think I should solve $$\sum_{k=1}^c n\lambda^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}\leq \alpha$$ and $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{c} n\lambda^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}\geq \alpha$$, but I was not able to get an answer.

Comment: I don't know a closed form for this.

Comment: Can I describe the rejection region with those equations? Is it a better way than saying the rejection region is $(\Phi^{-1}(c),+\infty)$ where $c$ is a solution to the inequalities and $\Phi$ is the normal function restricted to $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: You can describe it by saying you reject the null hypothesis if the sum is smaller than the critical value. If you were using a normal approximation, you'd need $\displaystyle \Phi\left( \frac{c - n\lambda_0}{\sqrt{n\lambda_0}} \right) = \alpha. \qquad$

Comment: Thank you, and if $\lambda_0<\lambda_1$ then $\Phi\left(\frac{n-\lambda_0}{\sqrt{n\lambda_0}}\right)=\alpha$, right?

Comment: @Gabriel : There you would have $\displaystyle \Phi\left( \frac{c-n\lambda_0}{\sqrt{n\lambda_0}} \right) = 1-\alpha,$ and then you reject the null hypothesis if the sum is bigger than that.